# Android WebView width flips from zero to screenwidth

Tags: android, webview, preload

I'm using a `WebView` to display content, and want it to be responsive.

So I'm preloading the `WebView` with content from another activity.

The speed has improved drastically but it seems that the inflated view doesn't match the parent width and height.

So when I set the `contentview` from the `onCreate` method. The view loads immediatly but the the content in the `WebView` is repositioning.

It seems like the `WebView` is inflated width a zero width, the moment I load it into the activity it fills the screen, and the content is jumping.

So here is my question. What could be the problem of this? Is there a way to set the width and height of a inflated view to match parent and to let the `WebView` prerender content the right size?

```
public static void preload(Context context) {
    MondriaanApplication mApp = (MondriaanApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    View pagesView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages, null, false);
    WebView pages = (WebView) pagesView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    //do parsing and webview filling

    mApp.setPagesView(pagesView);
}
```

and then from onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mApp = (MondriaanApplication) getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(mApp.getPagesView());
}
```

Comment: Share your effort with us. Show some code

Comment: Added some code, can't seem to figure out why the WebView is resizing after inflating